# Does changing the frame of the view affect renderInContext and UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext?

Tags: ios7, calayer, uigraphicscontext

I am trying to render the image of a scroll view even to the areas which is outside the visible area of the screen. I am resizing the frame of the scroll view to include the content size width and height.After resizing, I am doing a renderInContext and finally taking the image by UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext.
All I am getting is a square box of black color of certain bytes. If i do not resize the frame of the view, i get the image with incorrect frame.
Does changing the frame affect renderInContext? What can i do to get the correct image after resizing?